# What happened to the imperial archives stored at the Tabularium?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire

The [Tabularium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabularium) in Rome was used to house the archives of the Roman Empire.

Unfortunately, these archives do no longer exist. What happened to them?

[image: A 3D reconstruction of the Tabularium building]

Comment: Those documents written on pergamen the Goths probably used to make shoes, or gloves.

Comment: I would say @Alex that most probably they were overwritten. Writting materials were expensive, the Roman had no good ways of preserving them and, in fact, most of them would, a few decades after being written, contain data that was not interesting except for historians and serve for nothing than to waste space.

Comment: @Alex Actually, you might want to look into the Goths more in depth. They *were* Christians by the time they sacked Rome and while they were not particularly nice people, they were not so ignorant of culture as you suspect them to be.

Comment: @SJuan76 Sounds about right to me.